# Regular expression for this

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file and I would like to parse it using regular expression.
how can i extract the text block between "Entry #" to the empty line before the next "Entry #"

```
GmtOffset=120
GmtExistFlag=0
LocalTimeFlag=0
Entry #1
EventType=1
FieldType=256
FieldValue=12-05-2010, 11:00:00
FieldType=512
FieldValue=12-05-2010, 11:30:00
FieldType=1
FieldValue(3)=Jku

Entry #2
EventType=1
FieldType=256
FieldValue=15-05-2010, 06:00:00
FieldType=512
FieldValue=15-05-2010, 06:30:00
FieldType=1
FieldValue(3)=Lsh
FieldType=1024
FieldValue=15-05-2010, 05:45:00
FieldType=65536
FieldValue=1

Entry #3
EventType=4
FieldType=1
FieldValue(4)=STYL
FieldType=1024
FieldValue=13-05-2010, 11:00:00
FieldType=65536
FieldValue=1
FieldType=2097152
FieldValue=2
FieldType=8388608
FieldValue=-2147483648
```

How to ?

Thanks

Comment: Regex is not the magically solution to all text parsing. Sometimes, and here it's the case, a simple split or text reader can do the job.

Comment: i agree it's not magic but it's more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I concur with the solution by @ie, I think that solution will overlook the problem of the number following the `Entry #`. In that case Regex.Split will work.

```
string[]  matches = Regex.Split(inputStrng, @"Entry #\d+\s+");
foreach (string match in matches)
{     
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

[Splitting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) by the `Entry #` will give you what you want. Regexes are not necessary here. Just do split and remove empty lines on the end:

```
var blocks = text.Split("Entry #");
foreach (var block in blocks)
{
    // removing the line with the entry number
    block = block.Substring(block.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine));

    // removing the empty lines
    block = block.Trim('\n', '\r');

    // add your processing here
}
```

Comment: `Entry #` is followed by a number. I think the OP doesn't want that number in the block returned

Comment: @Steve ok, I've updated the sample. anyway, I've just threw an idea, further tweaks are possible